# 2 passports, 2 current ESTAs?

Tags: usa, esta

I have 2 current passports which are both the same nationality. I just have 2 as I travel a lot, and work need one to be able to apply for my visas. I have an ESTA from last year in one passport (which I forgot I had) so I applied for a new ESTA in my 2nd passport to go on holiday this year. Is my ESTA from last year still valid as well as my new one, or would my new ESTA have cancelled out my old one?

Comment: An explanation of what ESTA is would be good too....

Answer (score 4):

By inference from [CBP](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel) one does not cancel the other:

> Q:

I just got an email stating my ESTA has been cancelled because of a non e-passport, however my passport is an e-passport with the symbol on the cover.  What should I do?

> A:

Please check your application with your e-passport on the ESTA website.  If you submitted your email address on more than one ESTA application, the email could be referencing another ESTA application for a previous passport.  The email you received refers to the cancellation of the ESTA application of your non e-passport.  Your ESTA application with your current e-passport should still be valid.